# Why is new material dark in Cinema 4D?

Tags: cinema4d

I am new to 3D software and have just started with Cinema 4d. This is a very noobish question but when I create any new material in a project it always shows up pitch dark with very little mirror reflection.
I have even downloaded ready made package example from here

https://www.fattututorials.com/cinema-4d-ultra-realistic-silver-material-tutorial/

and doesn't show in my software like the example on youtube. It's much darker and the render is pitch black.